# context.database.create() throws exception invalid column name "Branch_Id"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a migration that got added once and applied successfully:

```
public partial class AddedTablesForBranchData : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.SalesArea",
                c => new
                    {
                        PostalCode = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Location = c.String(),
                        Branch_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.PostalCode)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.SalesBranch", t => t.Branch_Id)
                .Index(t => t.Branch_Id);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.SalesBranch",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Name = c.String(),
                        Contacts = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.SalesArea", "Branch_Id", "dbo.SalesBranch");
            DropIndex("dbo.SalesArea", new[] { "Branch_Id" });
            DropTable("dbo.SalesBranch");
            DropTable("dbo.SalesArea");
        }
    }
```

Sadly the the PostalCode is an integer. I had to change it to a string due to localization...

Thus some migrations later I added a new migration:

```
 public partial class ReCreateSalesTables : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("SalesArea", "Branch_Id", "SalesBranch");
            DropIndex("SalesArea", new[] { "Branch_Id" });

            DropTable("dbo.SalesArea");
            DropTable("dbo.SalesBranch");

            CreateTable("SalesBranch",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.String(false, maxLength: 128),
                Name = c.String(),
                Contacts = c.String()
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

            CreateTable("SalesArea",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(false, true),
                PostalCode = c.String(maxLength: 32),
                Location = c.String(),
                BranchId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128)
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.SalesBranch", t => t.BranchId)
            .Index(t => t.PostalCode, unique: true);  

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            throw new Exception("It has never been our intention to use a down migration, else data might be lost...");
        }
    }
```

Then I run into the "*a table con not have multiple identity columns*" problem due to **PostalCode** being a identity column and in the new migration I have **Id** being a column Identity

Thus I had to drop both tables in the new migration and re-create those tables with the new schema.

There seems to be no problem on my local machine/development environment But when I run the integration tests or before any test is run I do this:

```
 [TestClass]
    public sealed class InitializeDatabase
    {
        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext x)
        {
            using (var context = new LeadContext())
            {
                // Create database outside of the test transactions else you get a nice exception...
                context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.Create();
                new Configuration().FillEnums(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

It is deleting the old database and creating a new database using all migrations. This AssemblyInit method runs fine when I debug it, but after leaving the method some second later I can see this output in my integration test:

Result Message: Initialization method IntegrationTests.SalesDataTests.Init threw exception. System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name '**Branch_Id**'..

I am not able to debug my integration test directly as I never get there, so the problem must be the context.database.create() method.

Why is EF complaining that the old/former foreign key column 'Branch_Id' is invalid?

I do not understand that scenario.

Can anybody help please :-)

**UPDATE**

Question: 
What changed between AddedTablesForBranchData and migration ReCreateSalesTables ?

Answer: 
I introduced a property Id (identity column/string) and changed the property PostalCode to integer/unique:true.

**UPDATE 2**

There exist no fluent configurations about any SalesX table.

**Model**

```
  [Table("SalesBranch")]
    public class SalesBranch
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Contacts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalesArea>  SalesAreas { get; set; }
    }

 [Table("SalesArea")]
    public class SalesArea
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

        public virtual SalesBranch Branch { get; set; }

        public int BranchId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What do your models and fluent code look like?

Comment: @SteveGreene sorry I thought I posted them! Question is updated and I do not use any fluent configuration on both tables.

Comment: That seems correct. Could be some funkiness with how EF batches up consecutive migrations. Are you in a position to delete the last migrations up to and including AddedTablesForBranchData? Then roll forward with a new migration.

Comment: You mean delete ALL migrations before AND including AddedTablesForBranchData migration? Would that really help? Because then still BOTH troublesome migrations will be executed! Please correct me if you think I am wrong :-)

Comment: No, I mean that migration and after. The most recent ones.

Comment: By annotating the property:"        public virtual SalesBranch Branch { get; set; }
" with [ForeignKey("BranchId")] it fixed the problem! It seems the model were out of sync with the migrations!

Comment: Curious, because the models drive the migrations and BranchId should be considered a FK by convention. As long as you got it working. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

Comment: I also thought that and still think it but I overlooked that the parent table is called "SalesBranch" not Branch therefore BranchId did not work for the EF convention ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By annotating the property:

`public virtual SalesBranch Branch { get; set; }` with `[ForeignKey("BranchId")]` it fixed the problem!

It seemed the model were out of sync with the migrations!